# JavaScript: Not able to start with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am really new to JavaScript . I want to try  moment.js  but it doesn't work at all.  I wrote the following simple code.  More simple is not possible.   Can you help me to find what I am missing ? 
Thank you in advance  :)

```js
console.log( moment().format()) ;
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/da.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> test </h1>
    
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to add moment.js into your html. you are only loading the danish locale.

Comment: You are loading a locale file rather than the actual moment.js library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the base momentjs library, the url is:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>`

your code becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.buttflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/da.js"></script>*

</head>
<body>
<h1> test </h1>
<script>
 console.log( moment().format()) ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `moment` library CDN itself ([from here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/)), not just the localization package you had included.
The problem could be easily found if you open your explorer dev tools and [check for errors](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/da.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> test </h1>
<script>
 console.log( moment().format()) ;
</script>
```